# Unity, проверка наличия компонента в Editor

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Недавно решил поиграть с кастомным Unity Editor.

Что хотел:
     Есть моно скрипт `Main`, вешаю его на какой либо объект в сцене.У `Main` есть ссылка на другой определённый компонент -`Controller`.
   Затем этот Main смотрит Transform дочерних gameObject и ищет там компонент `Controller`.
   Если `Main` находит `Controller`, то всё хорошо, ссылка сохраняется и в инспекторе рисуется зелёный квадратик.
   Если не находит, или же `Controller` пропал, то рисуем красный квадратик, появляется кнопка Fix. При нажатии на неё `Main` снова пытается найти контроллер.

Код класса `MainValidator`:

```
 [CustomEditor(typeof(Main))]
    public class MainValidator:Editor
{  
        private Rect _rect;
        private Main _thisMain;


        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();
            DrawDefaultInspector();
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);

            _thisMain= (Main)target;
            _rect = new Rect(50, 350, 250, 70);

            if (_thisMain!= null)
            {
                if (_thisMain.IsTryed && !_thisMain.IsValidated)
                {
                    if (GUILayout.Button("Fix"))
                    {
                        EditorApplication.delayCall += ReTry;
                        EditorApplication.delayCall += Validate;
                    }
                }

                _thisMain.Validate(_thisMain);

                if (_thisMain.IsValidated)
                {
                    EditorGUI.DrawRect(_rect, Color.green);
                }
                else
                {
                    EditorGUI.DrawRect(_rect, Color.red);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUI.DrawRect(_rect, Color.red);
            }

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
        }

        protected void Validate()
        {
            _thisMain.Validate(_thisMain);
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(_thisMain);
        }

        protected void ReTry()
        {
            _thisMain.ReTry();
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(_thisMain);
        }

//endif
}
```

Код класса `Main`:

```
[System.Serializable]
    public class Main:MainBase
    {

        [HideInInspector]
        [SerializeField, UsedImplicitly]
        private Controller _controller;


        protected override bool ValidateAction(MainBase mainlocal)
        {

            Main main =mainlocal as Main;
            if(main==null)
                return false;

 //!!! вот здесь непонятно
            _controller= //main.
                gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Controller>();

            if (_controller== null)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        protected override bool ValidateCheckAction()
        {
            if (_controller== null)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Пролема в коде `Main` (там коментами помечено):
Если я при присвоении ссылки делаю так как в коментариях т.е.

```
_controller= main.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Controller>();
```

То ссылка находится и появляется зелёный квадрат, но если перезапустить Editor, то ссылка теряется и квадрат красный (при нажатии на Fix всё чинится).
Если сделать `Controller` как `public` или

```
_controller= gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Controller>();
```

То при перезапуске всё сохраняется.

Где то на уровне интуиции как то понятно, но не могли бы Вы конкретнее обьяснить, почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Controller))]
public class ClassName...........
```